How do I distribute an SSL certificate to a specific IP? C#
I created a program in C# that accesses an SSL and tries to distribute it to some IPs.
It executes correctly and returns success, but when I open the IP with SSL it doesn't work, only with http.
Program.cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text.Json;
using UnionFunctionality;
using Union_conf;

namespace Union_new
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Carregar as configurações do arquivo JSON
            string configFilePath = "C:\\union\\union\\union\\Config.json";
            Config config = LoadConfigFromJson(configFilePath);

            if (config != null)
            {
                // Obter os endereços IP e portas do banco de dados
                List<Tuple<string, int>> addressPortList = GetAddressPortListFromDatabase();

                // Certificado SSL
                string certificatePath = config.CaminhoCertificado;
                string certificatePassword = "";

                foreach (var addressPort in addressPortList)
                {
                    string address = addressPort.Item1;
                    int port = addressPort.Item2;

                    // Configurar e iniciar o servidor HTTPS
                    ConfigureAndStartHttpsServer(address, port, certificatePath, certificatePassword);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static List<Tuple<string, int>> GetAddressPortListFromDatabase()
        {
            // Simulação de obtenção de endereços IP e portas do banco de dados
            var addressPortList = new List<Tuple<string, int>>
            {
                Tuple.Create("teste.nomedaempresa.com", 443),
                // Adicione mais endereços e portas conforme necessário
            };
            return addressPortList;
        }

        static void ConfigureAndStartHttpsServer(string address, int port, string certificatePath, string certificatePassword)
        {
            var server = new HttpServer(new HttpServerOptions
            {
                Port = port,
                UseHttps = true,
                Certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword)
            });
            server.Start();
        }

        static Config LoadConfigFromJson(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                // Verificar se o arquivo JSON existe
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    // Ler o conteúdo do arquivo JSON
                    string json = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

                    // Deserializar o JSON para uma instância de Config
                    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Config>(json);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new FileNotFoundException($"O arquivo JSON de configuração não foi encontrado em: {filePath}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao carregar o arquivo de configuração: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

Functionality.cs:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnionFunctionality
{
    public class HttpServerOptions
    {
        public int Port { get; set; }
        public bool UseHttps { get; set; }
        public X509Certificate2 Certificate { get; set; }
    }

    public class HttpServer
    {
        private readonly HttpListener _listener;

        public event EventHandler<HttpListenerContext> RequestReceived;

        public HttpServer(HttpServerOptions options)
        {
            _listener = new HttpListener();
            string prefix = options.UseHttps ? $"https://+:{options.Port}/" : $"http://+:{options.Port}/";
            _listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);

            if (options.UseHttps && options.Certificate != null)
            {
                ConfigureSsl(options.Certificate, options.Port);
            }
        }

        private void ConfigureSsl(X509Certificate2 certificate, int port)
        {
            // Configure o certificado SSL para o HttpListener
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

            // Adicione a configuração SSL usando netsh
            string certhash = certificate.GetCertHashString();
            string appid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", $"http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port} certhash={certhash} appid={{appid}}")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process { StartInfo = startInfo };
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                _listener.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Servidor HTTPS iniciado.");

                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (_listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        var context = await _listener.GetContextAsync();
                        OnRequestReceived(context);
                        _ = Task.Run(() => HandleContextAsync(context));
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao iniciar o servidor HTTPS: {ex}");
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            try
            {
                response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                response.StatusCode = 200;

                string responseString = "Hello, HTTPS!";
                byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

                using (var outputStream = response.OutputStream)
                {
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao lidar com a solicitação HTTPS: {ex}");
                response.StatusCode = 500;
            }
            finally
            {
                response.Close();
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnRequestReceived(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            RequestReceived?.Invoke(this, context);
        }
    }
}

Config.json:
{
    "SenhaChavePrivada": "",
    "CaminhoCertificado": "C:\\conf\\certificado.pem",
    "SenhaCertificado": "",
    "CaminhoChavePrivada": "C:\\conf\\certificado.pem"
}

Config.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Union_conf
{
    public class Config
    {
        public string RemoteHost { get; set; }
        public string SenhaChavePrivada { get; set; }
        public string CaminhoChavePrivada { get; set; }
        public string CaminhoCertificado { get; set; }

        public static Config LoadFromJson(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Config>(jsonString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Erro ao carregar o arquivo de configuração: {ex.Message}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}

When I put the certificate pointing directly to tomcat (server.xml) it worked, when I put it to the tomcat IP it didn't work.
I would like to know if there is any way for me to do this by pointing directly to the IP.

...that accesses an SSL and... Do you mean "accesses an SSL certificate"? ... and tries to distribute it to some IPs... unfortunately that doesn't make sense to me, so I'm going to have to read all your code to have an idea of what you're doing. If you can add clarity it would be appreciated.

In fact, what I want is to generate an ssl acceptor and distribute it to some IPs. The purpose is that I use rabbitmq, tomcat and some other services that need to have the ssl certificate, and to avoid having to enter them one by one, I pull all the IP's from the bank and add the ssl to this service. But it is not passing the SSL correctly

The servers need more than the certificate, they need the certificate together with the corresponding private key. Now you say it doesn't work,... but more detail would be helpful. Do you get an error message on the server, or maybe one on the client, or some other indicator that tells you it isn't working? Those details may also be needed.

Sounds like you need to automate certificate enrolment and management. See eg https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/server-certificate-auto-enrollment
